# Nginx removing parameters from request in main page

Tags: nginx, redirect, webserver

Good day,
Please tell me how to remove the parameters of the GET request from the main page of the site and so that the rest of the parameters are processed. That is, if there are any parameters on the main page when requested, make a redirect to the site without parameters.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/public_html/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name mysite.com;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}


 location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but somethings on below lines should help you out

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/public_html/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name mysite.com;

location / {
  location = / {
       if ($is_args)
           rewrite / permanent;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}


 location ~ \.php$ {
    #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

}
```